sumif and countif from another Google sheet
I want to get the total sales count and the sum of a person from different google sheet.
I have tried:
 =countif(importrange("worksheet_name","'sheet_name'!H:H(range"),"referance Cell")"))

I need the count of the column H, sumif of column K and N in adjacent column to a new sheet.
Sheet (Revenue Tracker) where I need the data to come to column C (count), D & E (sum).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp7KJ6EDlAZBmoYpxOG0Sej4WKSSTJVr3VpNR1bUrH0/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Sheet (SHABNA TRACKER) from where the data should be pulled from column H (for count to column C in Revenue tracker), sum of column N of SHABNA Tracker to column D of Revenue tracker and sum of column K of SHABNA Tracker to column E of Revenue tracker.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eWNNhHikGB-5fClpMtQFROFI4tMa_G8_qOMz3uxzZ7k/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Hope this can be done.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION
Based on what I've understood, what you'd like to do is:

Count SHABNA TRACKER's H3:H to Revenue tracker's C3,

Count SHABNA TRACKER's N3:N to Revenue tracker's D3, and

Count SHABNA TRACKER's K3:K to Revenue tracker's E3.


If so, you may try the following formula for:
C3
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("1eWNNhHikGB-5fClpMtQFROFI4tMa_G8_qOMz3uxzZ7k", "18 June 2024 - 01 July 2024!H3:H"), A3)

D3
=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1eWNNhHikGB-5fClpMtQFROFI4tMa_G8_qOMz3uxzZ7k", "18 June 2024 - 01 July 2024!H3:N"), "SELECT Col7 WHERE Col1 = '"&A3&"'"))

E3
=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1eWNNhHikGB-5fClpMtQFROFI4tMa_G8_qOMz3uxzZ7k", "18 June 2024 - 01 July 2024!H3:K"), "SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&A3&"'"))

EXPLANATION
The original formula for C3 should work fine, given that the criterion is valid. As for D3 and E3, SUMIF wouldn't work on it since SUMIF and IMPORTRANGE are not working together and give the error Argument must be a range.
OUTPUT

REFERENCES

QUERY function
SUM


Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

If my answer helped you with your question, you may click the accept button on the left, which is the check icon, and upvote it. That way, it's known that the issue has been resolved. You may also review, What should I do when someone answers my question? for more information.
